# ¿Cómo guardar texto simple desde un archivo con CMD (batch) sin que compute los '&' y los '|'?

Tags: cmd, batch

Tengo el siguente problema. Estoy guardando el texto de varios archivos de esta forma.

```
for /f "Tokens=* usebackq Delims=" %%x in ("Nombre Archivo.txt") do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
echo %TEXTO%
pause
goto :eof

:concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%%line%
goto :eof
```

En los archivos solo hay texto, pero resulta que en su contenido pueden aparecer estos simbolos aleatoriamente ( '&', '|' ) y a saber cuales mas...

Lo que ocurre es que al guardar el texto en la variable %TEXTO% cuando  se encuantra con uno de estos simbolos, por ejemplo en el texto **(Copy & Paste)** se cree que es parte de la sintaxis de un comando y me salen errores como este.

**"Paste):"no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

Y el programa se detiene.

Bueno, he estado viendo posibles soluciones por ahí pero no me salen rentables porque habría que ir al texto y añadir caracteres de escape en cada sitio donde aparezcan estos simbolos, como se dice aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327431/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-batch-files

¿Alguna forma de evitar que pase esto?
Lo único que quiero es meter el texto de un archivo en una variable, tál cúal, independientemente de los caracteres que contenga.

Bueno, tambien decir que esto no me sirve (por si acaso)

```
set /p DESCRIPCION=<Archivo.txt
```

Porque esto solo lee una linea del archivo y yo quiero guardar todo el texto que contenga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hacer esto me ha sacado las castañas del fuego!! :-)
Ahora parece algo evidente pero es díficil darse cuenta de esto en primera instancia, sobre todo cuando solo da errores en ciertos cáractes cuando por esa regla de tres debería dar errores con todas las palabras. En fín, solucionado poniendo un par de comas al príncipio y al final!! :-)

Aquí lo dejo por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

```
set TEXTO="
for /f "Tokens=* usebackq Delims=" %%x in ("Nombre Archivo.txt") do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%"
echo %TEXTO%
pause
goto :eof

:concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%%line%
goto :eof
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por auto resolverte la duda me has ayuda a seguir con mi código <3

Comment: De nada!! Me alegro que te sirva!! Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

funciona bien pero esta es una forma mas corta solo que sin las comillas

```
for /f "Tokens=* usebackq Delims=" %%x in ("patatal.txt") do (set line=%%x)
```

Comment: puedes explicar que hace cada estructura del comando?